# What Kind of Pepper Plant is This?

Tags: identification, plant-health

[image][image]

My neighbor was growing this on her deck. She thought they were mini sweet bell peppers, but it turns out they're hot. I tried one, and to me it was very similar in taste to a jalapeno, with a bit more heat.

It doesn't look like it's in very good shape. Can it be salvaged?

Thanks!

Comment: if it has been colder going into fall, then the leaves would be expected to yellow and fall off. This is normal and doesn't necessarily mean the end of the plant's life. I've had several varieties overwinter outside in the southern US when the winter wasn't too cold. They drop their leaves and go dormant. They might hold onto a few very small leaves. But in the spring they'll come back strong.

Answer (score 1):

To save the plant, I'd say, harvest the fruit, and remove all the yellow leaves (and/or prune). Make sure it gets plenty of light. The yellowing leaves might mean it needs more nitrogen, but it looks kind of like they're about to fall off (in which case, I think maybe the plant thinks its life cycle is almost complete, which is why removing the fruit and pruning could potentially help to make it change its mind).

As for the variety (we can only guess), my guess is that it's [a Fresno chile pepper](http://www.tradewindsfruit.com/fresno-chile-seeds). Those are pretty popular, and they look much like that. The heat level sounds about right.

Answer (score 0):

Crossing, so hybridisation is common. Too many varieties have fruits in such form, so it is difficult to tell you which variety it is.

If the plant makes fruits (he did), she is healthy.  I agree that the plant doesn't seem  so. Maybe the plant needs more water, more sun, or just fertilizers, but until she produce flowers, nothing to really worry (but try to improve little what you think it is most missing). A note: stressed plants tend to get more spicy (hot) peppers, so this could be a reason this plant is very hot.